# how to reduce disc space if we have 10,000 input test data files

Tags: mongodb, testing, automation, automated-tests

We have 10,000 test cases each test case has a test input file XML.
So there are 10,000 XML files which are taking a lot of disc space about 2GB.

we have converted all the XML files to JSON files. which reduce a significant amount of space.

My Question is?

Is there any tool or another way we can reduce the size without affecting the performance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to compress and store data files on disk individually. When a data file is needed, just decompress it through the code and use it.

In case of Java, you can use java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream and java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream to compress and decompress files. File extension will be '.gz'.

Python also has 'gzip' module to support compress/decompress of .gz files.